# Assignment to nested lists in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I supposed, the result should be `1, 2, 3`.

```perl6
> my ($a, $b, $c)
> (($a, $b), $c) = ((1, 2), 3)
(((1 2) 3) (Any))
> $a, $b, $c
((1 2) 3 (Any))
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong (that is, ordinary assignment in P6 is designed to do as it has done) but at a guess you were hoping that making the structure on the two sides the same would result in `$a` getting `1`, `$b` getting `2` and `$c` getting `3`.

For that, you want "binding assignment" (aka just "binding"), not ordinary assignment:

```
my ($a, $b, $c);
:(($a, $b), $c) := ((1, 2), 3);
```

Note the colon before the list on the left, making it a signature literal, and the colon before the `=`, making it a binding operation.

Comment: Lexical with name '$a' does not exist in this frame in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

Comment: Hi @raiph thanks!
It works in a file, but strangely gives this message in REPL.

Comment: Ah, the REPL. The REPL is... caveat emptor. I imagine [the rich REPL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSZV8IXIsM4&t=0s&list=PLRuESFRW2Fa77XObvk7-BYVFwobZHdXdK&index=5) might do better.

Comment: Interesting, the Jupyter P6, which of course is also caveat emptor, has either the same error, or worse.

Comment: A lesson for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have the result be `1, 2, 3`, you must `Slip` the list:

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = |(1, 2), 3;
```

This is a consequence of the single argument rule: https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Single_Argument_Rule_Slurpy

This is also why this just works:

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = (1, 2, 3);
```

Even though `(1,2,3)` is a `List` with 3 elements, it will be auto-slipped because of the same single argument rule.  You can of course also just remove the (superstitious) parentheses:

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = 1, 2, 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are asking *What's wrong here", and I would say some variant of [the single argument rule](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/Single%20Argument%20Rule) is at work. Since parentheses are only used here for grouping, what's going on is this assignment

```
($a, $b), $c = (1, 2), 3
```

`(1, 2), 3` are behaving as a single argument, so they are slurpily assigned to the first element in your group, `$a, $b`. Thus they get it all, and por old `$c` only gets Any. Look at it this way:

```
my ($a, $b, $c); 
($a, ($b, $c)) = ((1, 2), 3, 'þ'); 
say $a, $c; # OUTPUT: «(1 2)þ␤»
```

You might want to look at [this code by Larry Wall](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2018-05-08#i_16141283), which uses `»=«`, which does exactly what you are looking for. It's [not documented](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/2010), so you might want to wait a bit until it is.